# How can I change the height/width of a shape in Microsoft Visio using the keyboard only?

Tags: microsoft-visio

How can I change the height/width of a shape in Microsoft Visio using the keyboard only?

I use Microsoft Visio on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

[image]

For example, in Microsoft PowerPoint 2013 I can use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +  <kbd>UP</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +  <kbd>DOWN</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +  <kbd>UP</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +  <kbd>LEFT</kbd>, or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +  <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> to change the size of a shape.

Answer (score 2):

You can resize shape width & height

1. With use **Size and position** window
   *! This way not clear only with keybord, because you can't activate Size and position window without keybord, ONLY with mouse* 
   [image]

   2. Or in **ShapeSheet window** (it works if you start in **Developer mode**)
      [image]
      For close **ShapeSheet window** press keys **Ctrl**+**F4**